# out of memory in MainActivity

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Our application android use a lot of memory in MainActivity ( 32MB )
[image]

we don't know how to detect and specify where is exactly the problem 
we try to comment all the code in MainActivity but No solution 
[image]
Can someone help us to detect where the solution exactly in our Code ?

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



                    private ArrayList<String> CodeBar = new ArrayList<>();
                    private ArrayList<Integer> id_Four = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<String> nomProd = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<String> prix = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<String> nomFour = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<String> adresse = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<String> tel = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<>() ;
                    private ArrayList<Float> ratings = new ArrayList<>() ;


                    private ArrayList<Integer> images;
                    private BitmapFactory.Options options;
                    private ViewPager viewPager;
                    private View btnNext, btnPrev;
                    private FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;
                    private LinearLayout thumbnailsContainer;
                    private ShineButton deleteLast;

                    private final static ArrayList<Integer> resourceIDs = new ArrayList<>();

                    Intent historiqueIntent;
                    Activity activity;
                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



                        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_promo);
                        title.setTypeface(title.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);




                        deleteLast =(ShineButton)findViewById(R.id.deleteAll);




                        final MaterialSpinner spinner_search = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                        //   final Spinner spinner_search = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                        ShineButton btn_search = (ShineButton) findViewById(R.id.searchView);


                        // spinner_search.setDropdownHeight(1000);

                        spinner_search.setDropdownMaxHeight(1000);

                        historiqueIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this , Histourique.class);
                        //ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Ville,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        // spinner_search.setAdapter(adapter);

                        VilleRemember vill = new VilleRemember(getBaseContext() , "" , 0 );

                                                spinner_search.setSelectedIndex(vill.getindiceSelected());
                        spinner_search.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

                            @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
                                VilleRemember vill = new VilleRemember(getBaseContext() , item,position );
                                vill.newSelectedVille(position,item);
                            }
                        });

                        btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                startActivity(historiqueIntent);}});


                        activity=this;
                        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                        //rotateAnimation(fab);


                        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                lanceScane(activity);

                            }
                        });

                        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                        toggle.syncState();

                        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onResume()
                    {
                        //  System.gc();
                        super.onResume();

                    }

                    //////////////////////////////////////
                    Timer timer;
                    int page = 1;

                    public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
                        timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); // delay
                        // in
                        // milliseconds
                    }

                    // this is an inner class...
                    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            // As the TimerTask run on a seprate thread from UI thread we have
                            // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    if (page >= 4) { // In my case the number of pages are 5
                                        // timer.cancel();
                                        page = 0;
                                        //   viewPager.setCurrentItem(page--);
                                        // Showing a toast for just testing purpose
                     /*   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer stoped",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */
                                    } else {
                                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }






                    @Override
                    public void onBackPressed() {
                        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        } else {
                            super.onBackPressed();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                        int id = item.getItemId();

                        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                    }

                    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                        int id = item.getItemId();


                        if (id == R.id.accueil) {
                            // Handle the camera action
                        } else if (id == R.id.historique) {
                            Intent i =  new Intent(this , Histourique.class);
                            startActivity(i);


                        } else if (id == R.id.prefere) {
                            Intent i =  new Intent(this , Fav_class.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom,R.anim.slide_out_bottom);

                        } else if (id == R.id.parametre) {
                            Intent i =  new Intent(this , Parametres.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        } else if (id == R.id.propose_nous) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, About_us.class));
                            finish();

                        } else if (id == R.id.contactez_nous) {
                            Intent i =  new Intent(this , contact_us.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }








                        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        return true;
                    }
                    public void lanceScane(Activity activity)
                    {
                        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                        integrator.setPrompt("Scanner");
                        integrator.setCameraId(0);
                        integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                        integrator.initiateScan();
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


                        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                        if(result != null) {
                            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                //historiqueIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this , Histourique.class);
                                //historiqueIntent.putExtra("serial",result.getContents());
                                //startActivity(historiqueIntent);
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RechercheResult1.class);
                                i.putExtra("CodeBar",result.getContents());

                                Historique his = new Historique(this , result.getContents());

                                his.insert(result.getContents());
                                his.remplireDateCode();
                                startActivity(i);
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Done! " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
                            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onPause()
                    {
                        //  System.gc();
                        super.onPause();


                    }

                    //------------------------------------------------------
                    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int i) {
                        return new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (i > 0) {
                    //next page
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                        page++;
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    //previous page
                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
                        page--;
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }



    // images dyal les produit proposses :
    private void inflateThumbnails() {

        System.out.println("==========>"+CodeBar.size());


        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_promo);

        if(CodeBar.size() == 0)
        {
            title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            deleteLast.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            deleteLast.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



        thumbnailsContainer.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < CodeBar.size(); i++) {



            View imageLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);



            TextView  price = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.prixprodtestcard);
            TextView  name = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.nomprodtestcard);
            TextView namfou=(TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.qtestockcard);
            TextView rating=(TextView)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            ImageView imageProd = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageprodcard);
            FloatingActionButton btnlike = (FloatingActionButton) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.likeButtoncard);

            btnlike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            price.setText(prix.get(i));
            name.setText(nomProd.get(i));
            namfou.setText(nomFour.get(i));
            rating.setText(ratings.get(i).toString());

            imageProd.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // Disallow View pager to intercept touch events.

                            System.out.print("=============>ACTION_DOWN");

                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            System.out.print("=============>ACTION_UP");
                            // Allow View pager to intercept touch events.
                            // v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                    }

                    // Handle Listview touch events.
                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;

                }
            });




            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(new TagDatabase().URL_IMAGFOU+"fid="+id_Four.get(i)+"&&code="+CodeBar.get(i)+"&&etat= -99")
                    .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
                    .skipMemoryCache( true )
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.waitloat)
                    .thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .into(imageProd);

            imageProd.setOnClickListener(onChagePageClickListener(i));

            thumbnailsContainer.addView(imageLayout);
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onChagePageClickListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),InformationsProduit.class);
                intent.putExtra("nomProd", nomProd.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("prix", prix.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("nomFour",nomFour.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("etatpromo", -99);//attttt
                intent.putExtra("telFour",tel.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("addrFour",adresse.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("idFour",id_Four.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("description",description.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("codeBar",CodeBar.get(i));

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered using a `class` instead of 10 ArrayLists with the same indexing?

Comment: Take a heap dump and look at what's using memory.  Its almost always bad bitmap usage

Comment: @GabeSechan I already share a screen of heap dump .

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I clear all the content of on create method
but I still had the problem

Comment: is the layout very big? or has a lot of image view or something or a big image? can you share a screen shot I ask because I worked on an app and I did everything right but the images were just a lot and the memory wasn't being garbage collected fast enough

Comment: @Hala.M is the images in drawable affect  memory if I don't call it ?
I clear my layout and my java class now my Main Layout clear and my ONCREAT method clear 
 but it was  useless

Comment: no only if you display it no background for the activity? also no static data of any kind?